# Laravel 7 - How to display properly the old input/s?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, redirect

I am trying to display the old/previous inputs when its validation failed before submitting the form inputs/values to Controller's validation but it only redirects back to the page with all input fields in form is empty or not showing the previous inputs.

Here's my controller code inside `store` function **(SaleController)**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'invoice_no' => 'required|unique:sales_h|max:255',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            //dd($validator);
            Toastr::warning('Invoice No. cannot be repeated or blank.', 'Warning');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all);
        }
    /* ...... */
}
```

Here's the snippet source code for my view blade file (`create.blade.php`):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method = "POST" action = "{{ route('sales.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="card-body">
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul class="mb-0">
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h5><i class="icon fas fa-info" d></i> Info!</h5>
                            A sales order is a document generated by the seller upon receiving a 
                            purchase order from a <strong>buyer/customer</strong> specifying the details about the product or service 
                            along with price, quantity, buyer details.
                        </div>
                        <strong><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required fields.</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="date" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Date <font color="red">*</font></label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('date') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    id="date" 
                                    name = "date"
                                    autocomplete="off" 
                                    value="{{ old('date') }}"
                                    required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="invoice_no" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Invoice No. <font color="red">*</font></label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend {{$errors->has('invoice_no') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    id="invoice_no" 
                                    name = "invoice_no" 
                                    maxlength = "15"
                                    value="{{ old('invoice_no') }}"
                                    onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" 
                                    required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="shop_name" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Customer Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend {{$errors->has('shop_name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type = "text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    id="shop_name" 
                                    name = "shop_name" 
                                    placeholder = "Customer Name" 
                                    autocomplete = "on"
                                    value="{{ old('shop_name') }}"
                                    required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for = "info" class = "col-md-4 col-form-label"><strong><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></strong> Sales Order Information</label>
                        <div class = "col-sm-12  {{$errors->has('product_information') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                            <textarea name = "product_information" 
                                    class = "form-control" 
                                    rows = "4"
                                    value="{{ old('product_information') }}"
                                    ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-12 field-wrapper">
                    <div class = "form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="id_raw_product" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Product Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="hidden" readonly = "true" class="form-control" id="id_raw_product_1" name = "id_raw_product[]" placeholder = "Product Name" required>
                            <input type="text" 
                                    readonly = "true" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    id="name_raw_product_1" 
                                    name = "name_raw_product[]" 
                                    value="{{ old('id_raw_product_1') }}"
                                    placeholder = "Product Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <a href = "/transaction/sales/product/popup_media/1" 
                                class = "btn btn-info" 
                                title = "Product" 
                                data-toggle = "modal" 
                                data-target = "#modal-default">Product</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="number" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="price_1" 
                                name = "price[]" 
                                value="{{ old('price_1') }}"
                                placeholder = "Price" 
                                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="number" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="total_1" 
                                name = "total[]" 
                                value="{{ old('total_1') }}"
                                placeholder = "Quantity" 
                                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "col-sm-2">
                            <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "btn btn-primary add_Button" title = "Add Row"><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
            <div class="card-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default float-right" name = "submit_create" id = "submit_create">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-footer -->
          </form>
```

Comment: You can't put `Toastr::warning()` after a `return` statement... The code will never get there. If you put that _before_ the return, you might have more luck.

Comment: @TimLewis tried placing it before the return statement but still no luck. anyways thank you for notcing that it will be unreachable :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your controller code like this -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'invoice_no' => 'required|unique:sales_h|max:255',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages()->all());

    }
}
```

and in blade file add this code -

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul class="mb-0">
           @foreach ($errors->all(':message') as $input_error)
                 <li>{{ $input_error }}</li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: the code in controller sides is working perfectly. tried to print the contents of $validator and it prints the name of input where the validation failed and its corresponding error message but it does not send in blade file and not displaying the error.

Comment: Have u add blade file code which I added in my solution? Please try this solution and let me know if it doesn't work. I will look into another solution. Thanks.

Comment: To print validation error in laravel , need to retrieve error message bag so I changed your controller code little bit and tried to print it in blade file. please try this and let me know.

Comment: yes I also added the code you provided for the blade file. I added it below the <form> since it will create a new div if an error occurs. but still no luck and getting the same issue.

Comment: edited my post. Only old inputs are needed to be displayed since I already have a Toastr for the error message when the validation fails.